# PCB Stack-up Window in Altium on the plane layer

Tags: altium, pcb-layers

It is a common feature of multi player PCBs to have a small window where one can look in and see a number for each layer of the PCB. It's used in manufacturing to show that all layers are included I believe.

We use Altium, which is easy enough to put this window in a signal layer, as it just needs to be added. However, when we come to plane layer it seems to get complicated. We can put a window into the plane without issue, but we cannot find any way to get numbers written on it.

Talking to our Altium support, they don't seem to have any ideas either. Has anyone done this? Does anyone know how to add the required text to this window?

Answer (score 3):

What *I* generally do, is just place the numbers on plane layers, and create cuts in the copper along the bar/window in all the other (plane) layers.

That way you get a transparent square with a solid number for each signal layer and a solid square with a transparent number for each plane layer, allowing you to also see if all layers were processed correctly.

Although these days I also often create small electrical structures to verify alignment and presence of all layers -if this is required at all-, as that takes much less space to verify than something you need to be able to distinguish through 1.6mm of some modern materials, with the exception of X-raying or such practices.